# Expand json from all in one to multiple rows

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Input = dictionary from pd dataframe

Output needed = json file with rows like this:

{"column1": Value1, "column2": Value1}

{"column1": Value2, "column2": Value2}

```
mergedfile = {}

for index,row in data.iterrows():
    index=index
    value1=row["column1"]
    value2=row["column2"]
    mergedfile.update({"column1":value1,"column2":value2})
    with open("sample.json", "a") as outfile:  
        json.dump(mergedfile, outfile, sort_keys=True)

print(mergedfile)
```

I get the output all in one row: {"column1": Value1, "column2": Value1}{"column1": Value2, "column2": Value2}

With this structure json cannot be readin properly.

How to achieve the rows under eachother seperately as in output needed stated above?

Comment: Keeping ```sample.json``` inside a for loop will it not overwrite the files on each iteration ? Can u add sample input.

Comment: sample input is just a dataframe with two columns two index and 4 values.

How to apply sample.json?

Comment: assuming ```data``` is a pandas dataframe, try this ```data.to_dict(orient='records')```

Comment: Thanks Sushanth, I tried this before, withour result, any other thought?

Comment: can u show couple of rows from input dataframe.

Comment: Input dataframe is defined by columns as date, name and texts (strings). I have 10 columns and hundreds of rows. Exampl of one row 4 columns: index, epoch, name, text.

0 | 1580023992 | Peter923 | this is awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `indent` parameter of `json.dump` to get well formatted output.

```
json.dumps(yourJsonOutput, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

**UPDATE**

here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import json

mergedfile = {}
data = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.5],[2,2.5]], columns=['int', 'float'])

for index,row in data.iterrows():
  index=index
  value1=row["int"]
  value2=row["float"]
  mergedfile.update({"column1":value1,"column2":value2})
  with open("sample.json", "a") as outfile:  
     d = json.dumps(mergedfile, sort_keys=True)
     outfile.write(str(d)+"\n")
     d = ""

print(mergedfile)
```